# Issues producing sklearn metrics for multi-label classification

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've implemented an EfficientNet pre-trained model on retinal (eye) images, and I can't figure out why my metrics aren't working! I'm open to using other metrics packages (keras?) if that is the issue.

```
# Loading a pretrained conv base model
input_shape = (256, 256, 3)
conv_base = EfficientNetB7(weights=None, include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)

dropout_rate = 0.2
number_of_classes = 3

initial_learning_rate=2e-5
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate,
    decay_steps=100000,
    decay_rate=0.96,
    staircase=True
)

en_model = models.Sequential()
en_model.add(conv_base)
en_model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D(name='gap'))

# Avoid overfitting 
en_model.add(layers.Dropout(rate=dropout_rate, name='dropout_out'))

# Set number_of_classes to the number of your final predictions
en_model.add(layers.Dense(number_of_classes, activation='sigmoid', name='fc_out')) #replaced softmax with sigmoid
conv_base.trainable = False

en_model.compile(
    #loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    #loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    #optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=2e-5),
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

history = en_model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=10,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    #validation_steps=None,
    validation_freq=1,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=[tensorboard_callbacks],
    use_multiprocessing=True,
    workers=4
)
print('Average test loss: ', np.average(history.history['loss']))
```

Metrics - this is retinal (eye) image data, and there are three classes/labels - diabetic retinopathy, glaucoma, and other. I'll show the code for the first class, where you can see that the numbers are the same for each metric, and the confusion matrix has zeros. I can't figure out what is going on!

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score
```

```
# y_true are the labels from the validation generator; we have three labels (DR, glaucoma, other)
print(f'Accuracy = {accuracy_score(val_generator.labels[:,0],[round(x) for x in val_pred[:,0]])}')
print(f"F1 = {f1_score(val_generator.labels[:,0],[round(x) for x in val_pred[:,0]], average='micro')}")
print(f"Precision = {precision_score(val_generator.labels[:,0],[round(x) for x in val_pred[:,0]], average='micro')}")
print(f"Recall = {recall_score(val_generator.labels[:,0],[round(x) for x in val_pred[:,0]], average='micro')}")
print('Confusion matrix =')
confusion_matrix(val_generator.labels[:,0],[round(x) for x in val_pred[:,0]])
```

Output

```
Accuracy = 0.7807953443258971
F1 = 0.7807953443258971
Precision = 0.7807953443258971
Recall = 0.7807953443258971
Confusion matrix =
array([[805,   0],
       [226,   0]])
```

The same code above (replacing 0's with 1's and 2's) produces these results:

```
Accuracy = 0.8244422890397672
F1 = 0.8244422890397672
Precision = 0.8244422890397672
Recall = 0.8244422890397672
Confusion matrix =
array([[850,   0],
       [181,   0]])
```

```
Accuracy = 0.6876818622696411
F1 = 0.6876818622696411
Precision = 0.6876818622696411
Recall = 0.6876818622696411
Confusion matrix =
array([[  0, 322],
       [  0, 709]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Keras and Tensorflow have already a lot of the [metrics](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics), if not all, that you mentioned if you are looking for alternatives:

```py
!pip install -U tensorflow-addons
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.python.keras.metrics import Accuracy
from tensorflow.python.keras.metrics import Recall
from tensorflow.python.keras.metrics import Precision
from tensorflow.python.keras.metrics import AUC
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

tf.math.confusion_matrix
tfa.metrics.F1Score
```

Regarding your `Sigmoid` activation function, you mentioned you have 3 classes; why not consider using a `Softmax` activation function which is actually used for multiclass logistic regression? You would also have to replace your `binary_crossentropy` loss function with `categorical_crossentropy` or `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` depending on how your labels are encoded. If you have a multi-label classification problem aiming to predict zero or more class labels (0, 1), then `binary_crossentropy` is the right choice for you.

Comment: The labels are 0's and 1's.

Comment: So one hot encoded? diabetic retinopathy --> 1, 0, 0, glaucoma --> 0, 1, 0, and other --> 0, 0, 1?

Comment: How do I import those metrics. import tf.keras.metrics.accuracy gives me an error ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'```even though I've imported tensorflow as tf. and I've also done ```from tensorflow import keras```

Comment: Not really one-hot encoded because each image can have a 1 in all three classes.

Comment: Check your tensorflow version and if it matches the versions with metrics available on the website

Comment: Ok, understood, then you can stick with `binary_crossentropy`, since you are dealing with a multi-label classification problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238303/discussion-between-yogesh-riyat-and-alonetogether).